# How to keep cloth from stretching infinitely?

Tags: cloth-simulation

Trying to simulate a balloon on a cloth ribbon. However, the rising balloon stretches the cloth infinitely, while I want the cloth to keep the balloon down. I have played extensively with cloth settings, to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Under the *Stiffness* tab in the cloth settings, turn up the *Structural* slider, that should fix it.

The *Bending Model* under *Physical Properties* must be set to *Linear*, otherwise, the slider will not show up.